# Vue methods mixins

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, frontend, mixins

I have method getNames inside my mixins file that returns names.

```
import { default as config } from '../config';
var methods = {
    methods: {
        getNames() {
            return axios.get(API + API.NAMES)
            .then( (response) => {
                if( response.status == 200 && typeof(response.data) == 'object' ) {
                    return response.data;
                }
            });
        }
    }
};

export default methods;
```

From my single template file I have imported the mixins/methods file. Now my problem is how can I get the return object data from **getNames** method. Coz when I tried to

```
mixins: [
            filters,
            methods
],
mounted: function() {
            var a = this.getNames();
            console.log(a);
        }
```

**getNames** method just returns a **Promise**

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axios.get()` call is asynchronous and it returns a `Promise`. It does not return the value from the anonymous function passed to the chained `then` method.

In order to access that value, you can chain a `then` method to the returned `Promise`, like so:

```
mounted: function() {
  this.getNames().then(a => { console.log(a) });
}
```