# how to pass api response value to calling method to parent component that calls it in vue?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I have a vue 2 project that has multiple components that gets images from firebase. Instead of rewriting the same api call to get the image in every component, i'm trying to make one method that can be reused for multiple components. I tried using mixins but for some reason the return value is returning before the api fills it with the image reponse.

Parent component:

```
import getImage from "@/mixins/getImage";

export default {
  name: "Test",
  mixins: [getImage],
  //data and other functions
  methods: {
    getPicture(product) {
      this.image = this.getImage(`products/${product.productId}.jpg`);
    },
```

My mixin getImage.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

export default {
  methods: {
    getImage(imagePath) {
      this.loading += 1;
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(imagePath)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = "blob";
          xhr.onload = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            return URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
          };
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          xhr.send();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return "/noImage.jpg";
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading -= 1;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

the above will return me an undefined, i also tried returning the promise itself based on this answer [Vue methods mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125637/vue-methods-mixins) like so:

Parent component:

```
import getImage from "@/mixins/getImage";

export default {
  name: "Test",
  mixins: [getImage],
  //data and other functions
  methods: {
    getPicture(product) {
       this.getImage(`frames/${product.productId}.jpg`).then((r)=> this.image=r);
    },
```

mixin getImage.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

export default {
  methods: {
    getImage(imagePath) {
      this.loading += 1;
      return firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(imagePath)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = "blob";
          xhr.onload = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            return URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
          };
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          xhr.send();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          return "/noImage.jpg";
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading -= 1;
        });
    }
  }
}
```

what happens here is also undefined, lastly i have also tried using a return object like so:

Parent component:

```
import getImage from "@/mixins/getImage";

export default {
  name: "Test",
  mixins: [getImage],
  //data and other functions
  methods: {
    getPicture(product) {
       this.image = this.getImage(`frames/${product.productId}.jpg`);
    },
```

mixin getImage.js:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

export default {
  methods: {
    getImage(imagePath) {
      let image = null;
      this.loading += 1;
      firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(imagePath)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
          const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.responseType = "blob";
          xhr.onload = event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            image = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
          };
          xhr.open("GET", url);
          xhr.send();
        })
        .catch(() => {
          image =  "/noImage.jpg";
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading -= 1;
        });
       return image;
    }
  }
}
```

but this also returns undefined, i know for a fact the api call is not the problem because if i console log the firebase call response it is correct, its just not passing the returned image to the calling method and the to the parent that i imported the mixin into. Im really stuck and not sure what else i can try here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use firebase storage getblob instead, that way we can avoid the entire thing with xhr. here is what I ended up doing to make it work:

```
import { getStorage, ref, getBlob } from "firebase/storage";

export default {
  methods: {
    getOneImage(imagePath) {
       return getBlob(ref(getStorage(), imagePath))
          .then((response)=>{
            return  URL.createObjectURL(response);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            return "/noProduct.jpg";
          })
        .finally(()=>{
        })
    }
  }
};
```